# what is sequential flooding?

Tags: database, memory-management, storage, rdbms, lru

This might be simple, but I can't get my head around it. Can anyone give me an example of sequential flooding? In the textbook I am reading and in Internet sources it is stated

> When the number of buffer frames is less than the pages in file, this will result in reading every page of the file. This is a nasty situation caused by LRU and repeated scans when
>
> # frames < # pages in file.
>
> Using LRU, every scan of the file will result in reading every page of the file."

But what exactly is it? Why does it happen?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let us say there is `2` buffer frames `Frame #1` and `Frame #2`, `3` pages in file `P1`, `P2` and `P3`.
What would happen if we scan the file twice(P1, P2, P3, P1, P2, P3) with `sequential scan`?

---

[image]

---

As you can see, using `LRU`, every scan of a page will cost a page miss. However, `MRU` will do much better.